# Custom devise session controller error with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I'm using devise with simple-token-authentication for user authenticate in a restfull webService. But when I make a requisition with a invalid token, I get the error below. What it can do?

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in.json" for ::1 at 2015-04-22 16:09:27 -0300
Processing by SessionsController#new as JSON
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 4ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  responders (2.1.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:205:in `respond_with'
  devise (3.4.1) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:11:in `new'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
```

Comment: Use a valid token...Can you be a little more specific on what your error is and what your looking to do?

Comment: I get this error when I use an invalid token. But I was expecting an error message in json like { "status":401, "message":"Invalid credentials"}. This error occur in new method, and I could not discover the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource)) do |format|
      format.json { render :json => { :message => "Forbidden"},:status => :unauthorized }
    end
  end
  ...
end
```